# Error in fontspec.sty

Tags: xetex, errors, fontspec, luatex

I downloaded a template for CV and one of the requirements was installation of `fontspec.sty`. Now when I compile the file the code file of `fontspec.sty` pops up in a new tab in TeXnicCenter and it points to errors in the file. Among which are

```
fatal fontspec error: "cannot use pdflatex"
```

It also shows that the `.sty` requires `xetex` or `luatex` to function which I have both installed. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

`fontspec` doesn't work with PDFTeX (and thus `pdflatex`) indeed. It requires XeTeX or LuaTeX (in recent versions). If the template you are using makes use of `fontspec`, it means it wants to use system fonts (TTF/OTF/AAT). You will need to compile this document using XeTeX (`xelatex`) or LuaTeX (`lualatex`).

Note that using XeTeX or LuaTeX may not be sufficient to compile this example, as you will also need to have the font required for it. If you don't have it, you will get a "font-not-found" error, and you will have to find the TTF/OTF/AAT font and install it in your system (hopefully, it's a free font).

Comment: Thank you, Raph and Werner, quite useful. Indeed Raph, now I have a font-not-found error. Googled around but it would be really helpful if you could tell me how to find and install the TTF/OTF/AAT font, please.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: I'd have to know which font that is first :-) The error message tells you the name of the font.

Comment: :Thanks a million. The font problem is solved. Now, upon compiling all errors (12 in no.) I get in the output file say xelatex> ! Undefined control sequence. Any clue how to get around this? Salutes

Comment: I think it's missing some info there. Can you open a new question with the full description of your error?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: if this answered your question, please check the mark under the number.

Answer (score 3):

You are compiling your template using `pdflatex`, as is suggested by the error message. Instead, you need to compile it using either `xetex` (or `xelatex`) or `luatex` (or `lualatex`). You can do this from the command line by typing `xetex file.tex` (since you mention that `xetex` is installed), or by defining a new output profile under the Built menu <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and compiling `file.tex` using this newly-created profile from within TeXnicCenter.